# setting up a (not annoying) multi-language input in Linux, X11

Tags: input-languages, xkb

currently I use XFCE and its Xkb plugin to switch between three layouts (us, russian and ukrainian; sometimes arabic input is wanted too).

on Windows, Punto switcher allows me to use one combination to switch between en/us layouts, and another to switch between all installed layouts.

here, <switch key> (caps lock) just toggles between layout 1, variant 1, layout 2, variant 1, layout 3, variant 1.

Ukrainian layout is fine at OpenOffice and IRC, but unfortunatelly don't want it in my emacs, firefox, and console. So looking for either:

- good replacement for standart switcher, to allow per-window (process name) layout management, or to allow two layout sets being switched by special key
- good replacement for XFCE environment itself. Maybe KDE4 supports the input in right way?
- a way to create a variant of russian layout, where ukrainian symbols are activated with compose key. I've detected (with a help of `xev`) that left/right winkeys are having different keycode, so going to use one of them as compose key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to start hacking XFCE's applets. It's a joy.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME allows  per-window layouts.

[image: "Separate layout for each window"]

Comment: Per-window, yes, but not "add layout(x) for window(x)"